# How to get request URL in Spring Boot RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to get the request URL in a RestController. The RestController has multiple methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` for different URIs and I am wondering how I can get the absolute URL from the `@RequestMapping` annotations.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/my/absolute/url/{urlid}/tests"
public class Test {
   @ResponseBody
   @RequestMapping(value "/",produces = "application/json")
   public String getURLValue(){
      //get URL value here which should be in this case, for instance if urlid      
       //is 1 in request then  "/my/absolute/url/1/tests"
      String test = getURL ?
      return test;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 93):

You may try adding an additional argument of type `HttpServletRequest` to the `getUrlValue()` method:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/",produces = "application/json")
public String getURLValue(HttpServletRequest request){
    String test = request.getRequestURI();
    return test;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and example. I know this method but was wondering if there is way to get url info using any properties in controller level but seems like this is the correct way.

Comment: Where is HttpServletRequest imported from?

Comment: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Comment: This does not include parameters

Answer (score 37):

If you don't want any dependency on Spring's HATEOAS or `javax.*` namespace, use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` to get URI of current request:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest();
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri();
```

Answer (score 9):

Allows getting any URL on your system, not just a current one.

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder
...
ControllerLinkBuilder linkBuilder = ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn(YourController.class).getSomeEntityMethod(parameterId, parameterTwoId))

URI methodUri = linkBuilder.Uri()
String methodUrl = methodUri.getPath()
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly, but is it possible to do without having a HATEAOS dependency? Although all the methods I tried depend on the request, one way or another, and I don't have that in my scenario.

Comment: Where does this go? How?

Answer (score 5):

Add a parameter of type `UriComponentsBuilder` to your controller method. Spring will give you an instance that's preconfigured with the URI for the current request, and you can then customize it (such as by using `MvcUriComponentsBuilder.relativeTo` to point at a different controller using the same prefix).

Comment: I'd never heard of `MvcUriComponentsBuilder` before! It's so useful for RESTful controllers!