# How to get the real uri address in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String test() {
    return "test";
}
```

I wrote an interface  I want to get the URI of the interface to do different authentication according to the uri.
But I visit localhost / test / can also be routed to / test
How do i set
What I get using getServletPath () method is also with /
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g77Bg.png)

Comment: you need to have test.jsp in your `resources/webapp` or else it would be return text

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710557/how-to-get-request-url-in-spring-boot-restcontroller

Comment: It's api  why use test.jsp

Answer (score 0):

you can get using below:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/test")
public String test(HttpServletRequest request){
String test = request.getRequestURI();
return test;
}
```